# Resize Div on Click and MouseDown

Tags: jquery-ui, resize

I'm using jQuery UI. #scene1 is currently being resized and works perfectly when I drag the edge. But, #scene1 needs to be resized when the users mouse is down on #LeftArrow.

I don't understand resize start() or stop() and how to use mouse events. Can someone please help me out?

```
$('#scene1').resizable({
maxWidth: 300,
maxHeight: 600,
minHeight: 600,
minWidth: 0,
handles: 'e',
});


#LeftArrow {
position: absolute;
background-image: url('../graphics/LeftArrow.jpg');
width: 51px;
height: 71px;
bottom: 156px;
right: 0px;
}


<div id = "codeSection"></div>

<div id = "scene1">
<div id = "LeftArrow"></div>
</div>

<div id = "scene2">
    <div id = "S1_Image"><img src = "graphics/S2_Image.jpg"></div>
    <div id = "CTAs">
        <div id="CTA1" class="transButton">Learn more</div>
        <div id="CTA2" class="transButton">Explore</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a link that calls a JS function that sets your width and height.

```
<style>
#LeftArrow {
position: absolute;
background-image: url('../graphics/LeftArrow.jpg');
width: 51px;
height: 71px;
bottom: 156px;
right: 0px;
}     
</style>

<script>
$('#scene1').resizable({
maxWidth: 300,
maxHeight: 600,
minHeight: 600,
minWidth: 0,
handles: 'e',
});   

function resizeLeftArrow(){
$('#LeftArrow').width(555);
$('#LeftArrow').height(555);
}     

</script>

<div id = "codeSection"></div>

<div id="scene1">
<a href="javascript:resizeLeftArrow();"><div id="LeftArrow">click me to grow bigger</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!

It's not working though. I think the $('#scene1').resizable() needs to be wrapped in a function. The arrow is like a handle within #scene1. I'm trying to do something like this:

http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/    Both #2 and #4

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish, as the new page you linked to has dragging demos, but the original question was on resizing?

Comment: Sorry, should've included a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/motionographer/gg2Gt/1/

This sample has functionality to open and close a div, but the same div needs to be draggable.

So, I have my draggable code, but it's currently not being used. I need the same button to drag open the div.

    $('#scene1').resizable({
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxHeight: 600,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 0,
    handles: 'e',
    });

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/139/](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/139/)